# How to make a table with selectable rows accessible

Tags: angularjs, html, accessibility

I have a web app with a view that renders a list of items, where the user is intended to select multiple rows, by means of a checkbox at the start of each row, and then subsequently invokes an action on those rows.  My question is: what is the best practice for making this accessible?  My first-draft Html looks something like this (it uses Angular.js directives, but that is not of concern here).

```
       <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="item in collection.items">
                <td class="checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox">
                </td>
                <td tabindex="0">
                        {{item.title}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

(My decision to use table, despite there being just one column other than the checkboxes, is because I also need a multi-column 'table' view of the same information.  That is not my main concern here).

When I ran an accessibility-checker tool over this, it complained that the checkboxes had no label.  But it doesn't strike me as sensible to add an artificial label (e.g. a row number) to it.  Should I be using row-scope, perhaps, to make the check-box into a  for the row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add an unique id to each input and create a label for that input. $index is a ng-repeat iterator offset of the repeated element (0..length-1).

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in collection.items">
            <td class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" id="{{'item-' + $index }}">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="{{'item-' + $index}}">
                    {{item.title}}
                </label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks.  I have a supplementary question, though, if I may: if my table has additional columns, how can I get it so that the user can click anywhere in the row to select the checkbox?  Html won't allow me to place the <label for...> around multiple <td> elements

Comment: Add a ng-model to the input, and use an ng-click on the tablerow to change that value? `<tr ng-click="yourValue = !yourValue">`  `<input ng-model="yourValue">`

Comment: Note that for better accessibility, you should not have a tabindex="0" which might override the click on the label